# Display icon overlay without restart explorer

Tags: explorer, restart, shell-icons

Please help me how can I display the icon overlays without restarting the explorer.exe?

The problem Im in stuck here is the fact that I must always close the explorer.exe in taskbarmanager and re-open it. I want the way no need to restart shell like that. Any way in C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a shortcut to a batch-file that [kills](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) explorer.exe and restarts it.  Restart it twice, once for the desktop and then for the explorer window itself (if needed (or just press Windows+E)).